# How to make cmd use newest version of javac?

Tags: windows, cmd, version, javac

In cmd on my machine javac is not up to date.

When using `javac -version` I get:

```
javac 1.7.0_67
```

While `java -version` gives me:

```
java version "1.8.0_121"
```

On my pc I have the newest version of javac.exe and If I navigate to it and use the `javac -version` on that specific file I get javac 1.8.0_121.

How do I make cmd use this version of javac as the default one?

Comment: You must find out where the files javac.exe and java.exe are located on your machine and correlate that with the directories in your PATH environment variable.

Comment: Type `where javac` in a command prompt window to find out where the executed command is actually located...